# How to SELECT all JOBS that using a DBLINK on oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, jobs, job-scheduling, dblink

Is my pleasure to say helo to all of you.
I need help on oracle to select all JOBS that using a DBLINK on oracle, to stop them during maintenance.
I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT JOB_NAME 
FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS, ALL_DB_LINKS
WHERE JOB_ACTION LIKE '%'|| DB_LINK ||'%'
OR DB_LINK LIKE '%'|| JOB_ACTION ||'%'; --this line is more like just in case...
```

Maybe you will have to play with `upper` like this:

```
SELECT JOB_NAME 
FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS, ALL_DB_LINKS
WHERE upper(JOB_ACTION) LIKE '%'|| DB_LINK ||'%'
OR DB_LINK LIKE '%'|| upper(JOB_ACTION) ||'%';
```

1. I have created a database link

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE LINK local 
   CONNECT TO hr IDENTIFIED BY password
   USING 'local';
   ```
2. I have created a job where I have used a name of the database link in the job_action section (name of the database link is `LOCAL`).

   ```
   BEGIN
      -- Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
      job_name        => 'Update_Status',
      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action      => 'BEGIN ;LOCAL; END;',
      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
      repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; bysecond=0;',
      end_date        => NULL,
      enabled         => TRUE,
      auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
      comments        => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
   END;
   ```
3. I have run this query from above:

   ```
   SELECT JOB_NAME 
   FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS, ALL_DB_LINKS
   WHERE JOB_ACTION LIKE '%'|| DB_LINK ||'%'
   OR DB_LINK LIKE '%'|| JOB_ACTION ||'%';
   ```
4. The result of the query was:

   ```
   |    JOB_NAME     |
   +-----------------+
   |  UPDATE_STATUS  |
   ```

If you want to search all objects to find your db link then try this:

```
select *  
from all_source
     , ALL_DB_LINKS
where text like '%'|| DB_LINK ||'%';
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But, It's still don't throw information *Thanks*.

Comment: You are welcome. Do yo know one job that uses one dblink ?

Comment: I'm trying to find one, but I don't know how.
I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. @VBoka *Thank*

Comment: Not a problem, but maybe there are none of them.. Lets just have that in mind.

Comment: Actually yes. There are many databases from which information is brought.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry, I can not be of any more help. You need to find one job to prove it to yourself that it exists...

Comment: Also, @OscaR, you have to understand that the JOB can run a procedure that uses a db link, right?